# Google Map Embed Code Not working in JQuery Toggle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, embed

Running a simple toggle -- In the div I have a Googe Map Embed Code (IFRAME) Snippet. When the toggle is activated all styling and text works, however the image of the map does not display ... Thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#classes").click(function(e){ 
    $("#class_breakdown").slideToggle("slow"); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }); 
}); 

<a href="#" id="classes">Click</a>

<div class="class_breakdown">The IFRAME Here</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You refer to something with an ID of *class_breakdown*:
`$("#class_breakdown").slideToggle("slow");`

However you don't have anything with that class in your HTML.  Instead it has a **class** of *class_breakdown* and should be referred to like:
`$(".class_breakdown").slideToggle("slow");`